# Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. (React-hooks React-native)

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

Previously I tried to make my change this code below, into React Hooks.

```
async startService() {
        if (Platform.OS !== 'android') {
            console.log('Only Android platform is supported');
            return;
        }
        if (Platform.Version >= 26) {
            const channelConfig = {
                id: 'ForegroundServiceChannel',
                name: 'Notification Channel',
                description: 'Notification Channel for Foreground Service',
                enableVibration: true,
                importance: 2
            };
            await VIForegroundService.createNotificationChannel(channelConfig);
        }
    }
```

and this is the code that I have been trying to make it into react hooks:

```
function foregroundService () {
    
    useEffect(() => {
      async function startService() {
        if (Platform.OS !== 'android') {
          console.log('Only Android platform is supported');
          return;
        }
        if (Platform.Version >= 26) {
            const channelConfig = {
                id: 'ForegroundServiceChannel',
                name: 'Notification Channel',
                description: 'Notification Channel for Foreground Service',
                enableVibration: false,
                importance: 2
            };
            await VIForegroundService.createNotificationChannel(channelConfig);
        }
        const notificationConfig = {
            id: 3456,
            title: 'Foreground Service',
            text: 'Foreground service is running',
            icon: 'ic_notification',
            priority: 0
        };
        if (Platform.Version >= 26) {
            notificationConfig.channelId = 'ForegroundServiceChannel';
        }
        await VIForegroundService.startService(notificationConfig);
      };

      startService();
    }, [])
 };
```

and I got an error:
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

I still newbie to this React hooks things

Answer (score 0):

`import React, { useEffect } from 'react';`

Import react in this file and return null for this function then it will work.
Why that so? -> Above you have created a function and for react to understand it as functional component it needs to have the import at the top and return null because you don't have anything to render in this function.

Comment: I already import like you said, but it still did not work

Comment: Can you share where are you calling this function? As this function can be called inside a component only.